# access to pages of yii application only to users that logged in to other site in the same domain

Tags: php, yii

There is a main site (it uses Drupal), there is yii application in the same domain (maybe in subdomain) that implements some functionality for users of this Drupal site.

If they are on the same domain, they can share cookie (session cookie).

What is the best way to give access to yii aplication only to users that are logged in to the main site from the same domain? How could I change yii application to give access to it only to users logged on main the site? Both site are controlled by the same people.

One of the possible solutions I see seems rather complicated and I don't like it: in yii application to ask login and passoword, then the script will try to login the main site (for example using curl), if logged it to authenticate user (it should work even applications are on different domains). So in this case we don't check user and password from database, but see if we can log the main site using credential passed by user. Is it a  viable solution? What is a better alternative?

Is it possible to share the same login for different applications on the same domain (subdomain) Drupal site and yii application in my case?

For example, in yii my session name in cookie PHPSESSID, for drupal site it's SES + hash(domain). Does it me that if user logged drupal site and will visit yii application on the same domain (sundomain), it will see both cookiers? Can I check by this cookie if user logged in drupal site (maybe to create some page on drupal that will give this info)?

Thank you in advance for any information that could give a clue.

Comment: you are looking for Single Sign On SSO..

Comment: I don't need single sign on. I wonder how to solve the problem I described sharing session between application.

Comment: yes its possible. Depending on what is your main application, you have to create cookies for the sub-application whenever user login to main application , see http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/202/integrating-yii-with-wordpress/ and  http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13932-external-user-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

you would have to ower right the CwebUser class i guess..

you can read this ! http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser

Comment: I asked how to check on yii if user is logged on the site from the same subdomain (maybe on different servers). Could you answer my question. You answer doesn't make much sense now.